# python and django: How to print a dictionary with specific rule on keys

Tags: python, django, sorting, dictionary

I built a data structure like this:

```
{ level: [ event1, event2... ] }
```

The `level` is one of the following: C(stands for critical), H(stands for high), M(stands for medium), L(stands for low).

I want to print all events in django template based on the level, C(critical) comes first, then H(high), M(medium), L(low). However, by default, which is what I have:

```
{% for level, events in dictionary.items %}
    {% for event in events %}
        do something with level, event
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I got H(high) printed out first, then C(critical), etc. I want to ask: How can I loop a dictionary in particular order? Or should I convert it into other data structure? Thanks.

**Edit:**
I think Steve's method works fine. It converts a dictionary into a list, each entry of the dictionary becomes a tuple:

```
[ (level1: [event1, event2 ...]), (level2: [event3, event4 ...]) ]
```

Comment: Just a heads up, ordering and dictionaries usually don't go too well together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered, so you will need to convert them to a list of tuples first:

Sort them as follows:

```
level_values = {'C':0, 'H':1, 'M':2, 'L':3}
sorted_dictionary = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: level_values[x[0]])
```

Then pass in your sorted_dictionary variable, and loop it in the same way as before:

```
{% for level, events in sorted_dictionary %}
    {% for event in events %}
        do something with level, event
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Further explanation of the important statement:**

```
sorted_dictionary = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: level_values[x[0]])
```

`dictionary.items()` gives you a list of tuples, representing your original dictionary.  So instead of a dictionary like this:

```
{'A':[1,2,3], 'B',[4,5,6]}
```

if gives you a list of tuples, for each key/value pair in the dictionary:

```
[('A', [1,2,3]), ('B', [4,5,6])]
```

You can think of a tuple as an list that can't be changed (it's said to be 'immutable').

This list of tuples is then passed into the `sorted` function.  For each tuple in the list, `sorted()` calls the lambda expression we supplied to ask for a sorting key.  Our lambda expression simply takes the first element in the tuple (i.e. the severity value), and accesses the `level_values` dictionary to find a sort value for it.

You can loop through the resulting `sorted_dictionary` (which is a list of tuples) either tuple by tuple:

```
for value in sorted_dictionary:
     print value[0]
     print str(value[1])
```

or Python will let you automatically split the tuble into separate variables:

```
for severity, events in sorted_dictionary:
     print severity
     print str(events)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not quite an expert in python, and I tried your method and it gives TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) ?

Comment: Sorry, I made some edits - did you try the most recent?  Note the `key=` keyword. @da_zhuang

Comment: That works! I guess it converts the dict into a list as far as I can tell? How should I loop though that?

Comment: @da_zhuang  I've added an explanation to my answer.  I hope that helps!

Comment: I've already completed my project with your help, thx man, saved my day

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to some other data structure. The easiest way to do this will be, instead of a dictionary, to pass into your template an already ordered list of lists, `[low_levels, medium_levels, high_levels]` or however you'd like it, and iterate over those. If you can, you might as well just use that as the representation of your events.

Answer (score 1):

Python `dict`s are not ordered. You'll need to convert it to a list, and sort it.

```
converted = [
    ('C', mydict['C']),
    ('H', mydict['H']),
    ('M', mydict['M']),
    ('L', mydict['L']),
]
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for level, events in converted %}
    {% for event in events %}
        do something with level, event
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, with your original datastructure, just loop through each category:

```
{% for event in dictionary.C %}
    do something with event, this is for Critical
{% endfor %}
{% for event in dictionary.H %}
    do something with event, this is for High
{% endfor %}
{% for event in dictionary.M %}
    do something with event, this is for Medium
{% endfor %}
{% for event in dictionary.L %}
    do something with event, this is for Low
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think your first suggestion makes more sense, your second suggestion I have already tried it, but gives too many lines of code :)

Comment: @da_zhuang personally I prefer the second option. It's far more obvious what's going on.